# Epson Stylus DX4250 USB scanner not working anymore

Tags: 11.10, usb, scanner, hal

I had been successfuly using the scanner of my EPSON Stylus DX4250 on Ubuntu (32bit) since I've bought it years ago.

Now I've updated to 11.10 64bit and it is not working anymore.

Have heard of some issues regarding USB, and some others regarding HAL, but I'm not sure where to start looking.

Here is what `dmesg` shows:

```
[53778.567908] usb 2-1.2.4: new high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
[53779.874059] usb 2-1.2.4: usbfs: process 25525 (usb) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

Doing a reboot, this is what I get:

```
[   72.024538] usb 2-1.4: new high speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[   73.266142] show_signal_msg: 30 callbacks suppressed
[   73.266145] simple-scan[1972]: segfault at 9691a85 ip 00007f146f3131a4 sp 00007f145fffbe00 error 4 in libc-2.13.so[7f146f2ca000+195000]
[   73.322406] usb 2-1.4: usbfs: process 2027 (usb) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  146.794098] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

Any idea?

Edit: the output of `lsusb` is:

```
...
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 04b8:0820 Seiko Epson Corp. CX4200 MP scanner
```

Comment: That segfault of simple-scan was when I was trying to see if it was detected. An empty list showed.

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb`? By the way, you can edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I've also installed xsane but it doesn't find any scanner devices :s ...guess simple-scan has not much to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how but it is working now... probably some update.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: If anyone still have this problem, keep in mind I've installed xsane (and probably some relevant dependencies). That could be the only difference from my setup.

Comment: Switched machines and now I'm having the same problem. I've suscribed to the bug nerochiaro suggested in launchpad and added a comment. Let's see how it goes. It hasn't been fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have often seen segfault issues when using the wrong libraries. Especially there are problems on 64bit machines with programs expecting 32bit libraries.

I have seen that simple-scan is not part of the official sources. Maybe it is not compiled against the 64bit libraries?

A possible test solution could be to install the 32bit libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

and try to use them explicitly when starting simple-scan in a terminal:

```
LD_PRELOAD = /usr/lib32/ simple-scan &
```

before doing that you should kill all running simple-scan-processes.

Maybe this helps you to get further.

Another solution would be to compile and install simple-scan from source.

Greetings from Switzerland, Michael

Comment: Thx, I've encountered some isues: simple-scan came installed on Ubuntu; ia32-libs came too; the second command errored `LD_PRELOAD: command not found`. I guess you may have meant `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/ simple-scan &` (two spaces taken out) but the behavior of simple-scan was the same :s

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in launchpad that tracks this problem. You may want to subscribe to it to see if when it gets resolved:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/simple-scan/+bug/888267

In the meantime, a good workaround is to downgrade simple-scan to version 2.32.0.1, which works with this scanner (I just tested this).
You can find 2.32.0.1 for oneiric in this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~robert-ancell/+archive/simple-scan/+packages